# Overriding BaseInput Widget in React JSON Schema Form v4

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm working with React JSON Schema Form v4 and trying to override the BaseInput widget with a custom implementation. I've declared my default widgets like this:

```
const defaultWidgets: Widgets = {
  DateWidget: DatePickerWidget,
  DateTimeWidget: DatePickerWidget,
  FileWidget: FileWidget,
  BaseInput: BaseInput
};
```

However, when I render a form, the custom BaseInput widget doesn't seem to be applied. Here's a snippet of my SchemaForm component:

```
import { AjvError, withTheme, IChangeEvent, ErrorSchema, FormProps, ISubmitEvent, Widget } from '@rjsf/core';
import { Theme as AntDTheme } from '@rjsf/antd';
 
const Theme = { ...AntdTheme };

const ThemedForm = withTheme(Theme);

const SchemaForm = <T extends object>({
  // ... other props
  widgets = {},
  // ... other props
}: SchemaFormProps<T>) => {

  const formWidgets = { ...defaultWidgets, ...widgets };

  return (
    // ... rest of the component
    <ThemedForm
      // ... other props
      widgets={formWidgets}
      // ... other props
    >
      {children}
    </ThemedForm>
    // ... rest of the component
  );
};
```

I've tried different ways to declare and override the BaseInput widget, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Can anyone guide me on the correct approach to override the BaseInput widget in React JSON Schema Form v4?

Also tried [this](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.2/advanced-customization/custom-widgets-fields/#custom-component-registration) approach, using uiSchema, but can't make it work.